# how to change date format in moment of any column of smart table in angular?

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

This is my custom **pipe**, which i am using to change date in **moment**.
eg:1 month ago

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({ name: 'createdDate' })
export class MomentPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(createdDate:Date) {
       const m=moment("createdDate").fromNow()
       return m;
    }

}
```

this object in which use to display table heading column .

```
settings = {`enter code here`
      createdDate: {
        title: 'Date Created',
         valuePrepareFunction: (createdDate) => {
          if (createdDate) {
        return new MomentPipe().transform(createdDate ,  'M/d/yyyy');
          }
        return null;
    }, } } };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your pipe code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({ name: 'createdDate' })
export class MomentPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(createdDate:Date) {
       const m=moment(createdDate).fromNow()
       return m;
    }

}
```